# JavaScript multidimensional array checks

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a problem with my arrays. I create them (which I'm not sure is correctly designed) but having difficulty understanding how to do checks on it.

My array is created like this:

```
id              = i++;
uid             = my_id;
imgwidth        = img[0].width;
imgheight       = img[0].height;
spritea[uid]    = new Array();
spritea[uid][0] = abposx;
spritea[uid][1] = abposy;
spritea[uid][2] = imgwidth;
spritea[uid][3] = imgheight;
```

I'm only assuming this is the correct way to store information about an image's position and give it a unique id.

I then want to do checks on the follow example criteria:

```
if (x > spritea[0] && x < spritea[0]+spritea[2]){
    var uid = //get the UID of the array ;
}
```

But i think i have structured my array wrong? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object. It's cleaner:

```
function create_image(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.height = 0;
    this.width = 0;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

my_image = create_image(++i);
my_image.width = img[0].width;
my_image.height = img[0].height;
my_image.x = abposx;
my_image.y = abposy;​
```

---

For searching, try this:

```
found_image = false;

for (var i = 0; i < spritea.length; i++) {
  if (spritea[i].width == 4) {
    found_image = spritea[i];
    break;
  }
}

if (found_image) {
  // found_image is your image
}
```

Comment: how would i do an if statement to grab the id ?

Comment: If you look at the first post, im trying to get [uid] value from checking the values in the array. But i think i have made the array wrong =/

Comment: I'm probably not seeing what you mean by "checks". Can you explain what you think that word means?

Comment: basically trying to get the uid by using if statement on values lets say:
sprite[uid][0] = 5 sprite[uid][1]= 10

i need to get the "uid" where 0  = 5 and 1 = 10. Thats a simplified explaination

Comment: The problem is uid is a id carried in a database it could be for example starting at 3000 odd =/ depending on the user's ID not sure a for loop with a counter is going to be efficient?

Comment: If you don't know the ID of the user, you'll have to look for it. How else can you do it?

Comment: im not sure unless theres a better way to create the array =/

Comment: You could create a dictionary for every property that maps every element's (unique) property back to its unique element.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want array of "sprite" objects

```
var sprites=[];

sprite[123] = { x:aposx, y:aposy, width:imgwidth, height:imgheight };
```

and check like

```
var sprite = sprites[1];
if (x < sprite.x && sprite.x + sprite.width < x)
{.... }
```

Comment: I can't use sprites[1] because the value of [1] is what im trying to retrieve, aka im trying to get the "uid" by checking the array's values. Which ever matches = the uid i grab =/ But if i can't use uid in the array how do i structure the array? There are many uid's that will be loaded all having their own information

Answer (score 0):

The test you are doing is incorrect as you need to include the `uid`

i.e.

```
if (x > spritea[someuid][0] && x < spritea[someuid][0]+spritea[someuid][2]){
```

But this might be better:

```
function Image(id, x, y, w, h)
{
   this.width = w;
   this.height = h;
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.IsXInside = function(x) { return (x > this.x && x < (this.x + this.width)); };
}
```

You create images:

```
spritea[uid] = new Image(id, abposx, abposy, imgwidth, imgheight);
```

Then the test becomes

```
if (sprite[someuid].IsXInside(x))
```